# can i build facebook canvas app without buying ssl?

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-canvas

i want to build faceook canvas app ,but when I started I faced a problem with https URL canvas and SSL certificate , that means my app domain must support this certificate " as I understood". which is become required from facebook .
Is there any way to exceed this problem without buying the SSL certificate ?
or is thee any free web hosting that support SSL certificate ? 
i need any thing that can solve this problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Should try this, you can get a free certificate on this tutorial..
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Canvas or Page/Tab Apps without SSL - meaning, everything that runs on facebook.com.

There are some free hosts with SSL, for example:

- https://www.heroku.com/
- https://www.openshift.com/